# Google Drive API Query string for finding files shared outside of the domain

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using a service account with access to domain-wide files.

What would be the query string that will return all files across the Google Workspace domain that are shared (either as editor or viewer) with anyone who isn't in the domain?

Answer (score 0):

### To find files that are shared by a user with anyone who isn't in the domain you can use the query string

```
q: "visibility='anyoneCanFind' or visibility='anyoneWithLink'"
```

See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms).

- Mind that to perform this request for all users in your domain, you need to loop through all your users and [impersonate](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) them sequentially with the service account.